# Angular async detect changes

Tags: angular, asynchronous, testing

How can I "detect changes" in testing Angular without testbed?

With a component, I will have this:

```
it('should work', async(() => {
  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
  // do some async call
  fixture.detectChanges();   // <=== This is what I want
  expect(something).toEqual(somethingElse);
});
```

With a service, I don't always have a testbed. How to tell angular to wait before asserting? Example:

```
it('should work', async(() => {
  const service = new MyService();
  const sub = service.emitter$.subscribe((val) => {
    // expect(val).toEqual(otherVal);
  });
  service.doAsyncWork();
});
```

How to get these connected? What if I have two phases to check (e.g. once before that async work, once after, but all after some initial period)?

Answer (score 1):

use `fakeAsync` with the `tick` function to simulate time period.

```
it('should work', fakeAsync(() => {
  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
  // do some async call
  tick(10000);    
  expect(something).toEqual(somethingElse);
});
```

Comment: That's a temporary solution, in some occasions I depend on things outside my control for this incoming data. Thanks though.